# while setup of azure-search-openai-demo - " Got an error while reading> Error communicating with OpenAI: URL has an invalid label. --> skipping file"

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-form-recognizer, azure-openai

i was implementing azure ai chat bot with custom data, while reading the pdf file uploaded got the following error for all files

```
`Running "prepdocs.py"
Ensuring search index gptkbindex exists
Creating gptkbindex search index
Processing files...
Using local files in ./data/*
Processing './data/Benefit_Options.pdf'
    Uploading blob for page 0 -> Benefit_Options-0.pdf
    Uploading blob for page 1 -> Benefit_Options-1.pdf
    Uploading blob for page 2 -> Benefit_Options-2.pdf
    Uploading blob for page 3 -> Benefit_Options-3.pdf
Extracting text from './data/Benefit_Options.pdf' using Azure Form Recognizer
Indexing sections from 'Benefit_Options.pdf' into search index 'gptkbindex'
Splitting 'Benefit_Options.pdf' into sections
    Got an error while reading ./data/Benefit_Options.pdf -> Error communicating with OpenAI: URL has an invalid label. --> skipping file`
```

[Git url](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo/tree/c8b8486d68527026b0660a3a75cc4e5e376793c1#using-a-non-azure-openai-instance)

i am using Using a non-Azure OpenAI instance

To use an existing non-Azure OpenAI account, follow these steps before running azd up

```
Run azd env set OPENAI_HOST openai
Run azd env set OPENAI_ORGANIZATION {Your OpenAI organization}
Run azd env set OPENAI_API_KEY {Your OpenAI API key}
Run azd up
```

which i set like above